# Looker Studio - Avg. If type of formula

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio, looker

I got a data set that looks like this:

| Date | Business Name | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.23 | Business #1 | $100 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #2 | $100 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #1 | $200 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #2 | $100 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #1 | $300 |

I want to create a field that will show me the average revenue for each business and will allow me to calculate the difference of a specific row from that average. So it should look like this:

| Date | Business Name | Revenue | Avg. Rev. | Diff. From Avg. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.23 | Business #1 | $100 | $200 | $-100 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #2 | $100 | $100 | $0 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #1 | $200 | $200 | $0 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #2 | $100 | $100 | $0 |
| 1.1.23 | Business #1 | $300 | $200 | $100 |

My data set is a Google Sheet, and I could calculate it there with Average If, but it will then not allow me to look at averages and differences that are filtered by date in Looker Studio.
When i'm using Looker's Avg formula - it calculates it base on the entire data, without the group by business name